# Force close when Orientation Changes with open Date DialogueFragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-fragments

I have an Activity and All i want is

> Activity--> OnClick of Some layout (That has textview)-->Open
>   Datepicker--> set selected value in txtvalue

i want to aceess Datepicker Using DialogFragment with Below Code.

```
package com.app.ourforms.date;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    TextView txt;

    public DatePickerFragment() {
    }

    public DatePickerFragment(TextView txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceSateate) {

        Log.i("TAG", "Inside onCreateDialog");
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Inside onDateSet");
        txt.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        // Do something with the date chosen
    }
}
```

Above code Worked fine when Device does not change its orientation. But When Datepicker is shown and Orientation Changes i am getting force close as Below

```
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at com.app.ourforms.date.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:39)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:116)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-04 07:34:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my method for calling DatePickerFragment

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Inside showDatePickerDialog");
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment((TextView)v);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
```

Please help me to get out of this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am Not Sure this Solution Work for you but you can try it out.

The Problem you are facing its because your Activity Reloads every time your Orientation Changes. you can call `OnConfigurationchanged()` method and inside Menifest file you can set Configuchanges to `orientation|screensize`

By Doing this your Activity will not load when orientation Changes and you  will not get longer face the Problem you are Currently Facing.

May Help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your TextView reference is null.  The NPE is on line 39 of your DatePickerFragment.  The reason its null is because when the orientation changes the entire view hierarchy is recreated, and the reference to the TextView that you passed in to your DatePickerFragment no longer exists.

Instead of passing in the TextView instance, try passing in the ID of the TextView.

```
new DatePickerFragment(v.getId());
```

Then implement

```
public Bundle onSaveInstanceState ()
```

and

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to save and restore the ID of your TextView for when your DatePickerDialog is destroyed and recreated.

You will then need to use

```
getActivity().findViewById(your_text_view_ID)
```

to find your TextView instance in the view hierarchy so that you can set it's text.

Comment: I agree. When Android rebuilds your fragment it calls the default constructor (`public DatePickerFragment() {}`)... To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it."

Comment: @Akos Cz: I knew why i am getting this. i want to overcome this situation by modifying this code. can you help me how can i pass this textview id to fragment?